# Difference of quasiconcave functions has unknown curvature (CVXPY)

Tags: cvxpy

I am attempting to model an allocation problem via (quasi)convex optimization: given a matrix of unknowns X containing the amount of a certain product in a certain moment and its value C, i want to maximize the resulting income `cp.sum(cp.multiply(X, C))`.
Among close/equivalent solutions, i want to have the least amount of different products types in inventary, `- cp.sum(cp.maximum(0, cp.sign(X))`, which counts the number of non-null entries in X as a penalty.
According to cvxpy, both functions are quasiconcave (the first is affine, and the second quasilinear), but when i compose them linearly, `cp.sum(cp.multiply(X, C)) - cp.sum(cp.maximum(0, cp.sign(X))`, the resulting problem has an UNKNOWN curvature, and refuses to solve since not 'DQCP'.
The problem is simplified, as there are additional parameters and weights, and in the constrains X is bound to be non-negative and to satisfy space availability, but this simple version reproduces this unexpected behavior.
Is the bug in cvxpy or in my math?

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvxpy

Answer (score 0):

The difference of two quasiconcave functions is not necessarily quasiconcave, so this operation is not permitted in CVXPY.